# Is there implementation of tri-planar mapping in Cycles renderer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, add-on, shaders

Is it possible to have tri-planar mapping in cycles? 
Like in corona renderer or fstorm?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Yes, it's called box mapping (or cube projection if you are unwrapping UVs).

Answer (score 2):

Use the Box mapping option for texture and adjust the Blend slider how much to mix the 3 projections on their edges:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jaroslav, I send a question on the main page to contact you, but I think they will delete it. So maybe through this post. I am from www.bba.studio, we will create a series (na motivy cesty do pravěku od karla zemana) And we would like to build blender pipeline (czech republic). Please contact me at marcel@bba.studio