# Mapping Node, Box projection, and rotation

Tags: texturing, transforms, vector-mapping

**Goal**

I'm trying to map a texture on a cube;

Since my texture is not exactly fitting the correct orientation, I need to rotate it. The results are not as expected.

**Setup description**

I'm using the setup shown in the following pictures. I've set the projection mode to Box have the texture visible on all faces. Texture mode is set on Repeat to avoid undesired clamping (default value).
What I'm trying to achieve is to have the planks horizontal instead of vertical on the front face (rotate around X axis). The rotation is applied in a Mapping Node.

**Results**

The face I need is properly rotated, but the others get this blurry effect, which reminds me of the "Clamp" mode in OpenGL. Is this expected behavior ? How to solve this ?

**Additional note (edits) **

Both the cube and the material are simplified versions of the original problem. The meshes I have are more complex, a few thousands faces, and with complex shapes (such as switches or sockets outlets). Very few faces are not aligned with the world axes, and thus they can be ignored. The material needs to be applied on various shapes, so UV map can't be made manually. The purpose of this is to automatically create a diffuse map of each textured item, where every face with a similar direction/normal would have a similar rotation applied.

For simplificity sake, the cube seems to be a good sample

[image: Original node][image: Rotated version]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there implementation of tri-planar mapping in Cycles renderer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154172/is-there-implementation-of-tri-planar-mapping-in-cycles-renderer)

Answer (score 3):

> "I'm trying to map a texture to a cube"

Perhaps a simpler way of mapping a texture to a cube and have control of the orientation of the texture on each of the 6 faces is to use UV mapping?

Starting with the node setup you have already :

1. In the **Texture Coordinate** node change to **UV**, and the **Mapping** node change to **Point** (and reset the rotation and scale to Zero).
2. Drag open a new viewport and change **Editor Type** to **UV Editor**.
3. **3D viewport** > **Edit Mode** > select the cube, then <kbd>U</kbd> to open the **UV Mapping** menu and choose the **Reset** option. This will reset the UV's so that each face of the cube is mapped to the complete UV space. (Each face stacked one above the other).
4. **3D Viewport** > select the face that you would like to change the orientation of the texture.
5. In the **UV Viewport** > select the face (if it is not already highlighted in orange then use the <kbd>A</kbd> key to select it) and rotate it 90° with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]

Or you can probably find the answer here http://www.blenderinsight.com/beginners-guide-to-cycles-nodes-the-procedural-way/  Under the chapter titled **Object (with no reference object)** :)

Comment: Hello, thanks ! 
I should have mentionned that the cube example is just for the exercise; The real objects are actually more complex than that, and the material should be applied on many different shapes. I expect artefacts on faces which are non-orthogonal to the axes, but those are very rare in my samples; Hence the simplification of the question to the cube sample. I'm editing the question to clarify this, sorry.

Comment: Even better, UV's are the way to go @Antoine

Comment: @brockmann I'm not sure : I would need to edit thousands of faces, which doesn't seem to be practical. As a matter of fact, I don't want to rotate 1 single face, but every faces that are aligned with the corresponding axis. The choice of the box mapping reflects this. In "simple" situations though, I agree the UV would be the way to go

Comment: I'm sure about this. The only other option you have is tri-planar mapping: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164187/31447 @Antoine

Comment: Aah ! Tri-planar mapping seems to be exactly the term I was missing to explain what I'm trying to achieve. "Standard" triplanar mapping has the exact same issue I was describing, but by looking online how to do rotations with tri-planar mapping, I found how to solve the issue in a very satisfying way : 

https://artisticrender.com/blender-box-mapping-workflow-a-quick-look/

The link also contains a link to a Blender file with all the maths included.
I'm not sure how to mark this as solved : Should I let you create an answer with these links or should I do it ?

Comment: The link you shared is just an extended version of [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164187/31447) in my comment before @Antoine There is no heavy math to do, it's just the image texture node set to box, done. And again, depends on the case but for a cube you probably want UV's (and you already have it) so I'd accept this answer. However, if you have something different in mind and asking a question about something else it's not that fair for the other users trying to solve your issue. If tri-planar mapping is what you want, I going to search for a duplicate. Cool?